# Is it possible to extend a UK permitted paid engagement visa?

Tags: visas

I applied for a UK PPE visa back in September from the USA for a November gig. However the visa office took so long that is now November and they're giving me a month visa that ends mid December. I can't travel to the UK that time so I was wondering if it's possible to extend the visa through the end of January since I could travel at that time. Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2):

No. Immigration rules do not allow extensions https://www.gov.uk/permitted-paid-engagement-visa

Comment: Even if they did allow extensions, I don't think it would be applicable in this case, since an extension requires you're already in the country.